# Issuing native system commands in Scala

Tags: scala, system, command

I want to issue a native system command from a Scala program, and perhaps trap the output. ("ls" comes to mind. There may be other ways to get directory information without issuing the command, but that's beside the point of my question.) It would correspond to os.system(...) in Python.

I've looked in "Programming in Scala". I've looked in O'Reilly's "Programming Scala". I've Googled several combinations of terms. No luck yet. Can someone out there give me an example, or point me at a resource where I can find an example?

Comment: Shouldn't you flag the right answer. That would be a nice thing to do and it gives people that see your questions in the future an extra incentive to answer. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Best way to do that is to use [scala.sys.process](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/index.html).

Comment: Comment by anonymous user: Check also for `scala.sys.process.Process`.

Comment: @Anne Thanks, I have updated the answer to point to the ScalaDoc. That package *is* the Process library, which has found its way into the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

```
import scala.sys.process._

val vimLocation: String = "whereis vim" !!
```

[reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder)

Answer (score 1):

Scala is not different from Java in this area, since you can call any Java API functions using Scala's interop features. See for example, [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `sys.process` easily:

**Executing system commands and getting their status code (exit code):**

```
import sys.process._

val result = "your_command" !
println("result = "+result) // result contain zero for success or non zero for fail
```

**Getting output from system commands:**

```
import sys.process._

val result = "your_command" !!
println("result = "+result) // result contain output from the command
```

You have several other options (pipeline, Redirect STDOUT, Append to STDOUT and ...), you can see [this link](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-execute-exec-external-system-commands-in-scala).

Answer (score 0):

Scala has complete interoperability with Java. So you can call the system commands from Scala as you would from Java. See [this](http://devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016/) to see how to call system commands from Java.

Comment: See the other answers, Scala's library makes things much more convenient.