# scala call to linux lsof command searching directories?

Tags: scala, process

How do I properly use scala to call lsoft +d on a directory?

Example:

```
import scala.sys.process._

("lsof +d /home/brad")
```

Comment: Start here probably: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.sys.process.package

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064994/issuing-native-system-commands-in-scala

Comment: -1. Do you actually have a concrete problem that needs to be solved, or do you just need references to get started? Google is usually quite good for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it would be just

```
import sys.process._
"lsof +d /home/brad".!!
```

or

```
Seq("lsof", "+d", "/home/brad").!!
```

The problem is that this process may have a non-zero exit value, and then the `!!` method just throws an exception and you don't get the result string.

As a workaround, the following seems to work even in the presence of exit value 1:

```
Seq("lsof", "+d", "/home/brad").lines_!.mkString("\n")
```

If you do wish to check the exit value as well, you can capture the output in a process logger:

```
var lines = Vector.empty[String]
val log = ProcessLogger(lines :+= _)
val p   = Seq("lsof", "+d", "/home/brad").run(log)
val res = p.exitValue // blocks until process is finished and returns the exit value
val s   = lines.mkString("\n") // the resulting output
```